# Creating a formula on Excel for my table

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to create a formula that will auto update when more information is added to my table and when numbers change. I have created a table that shows how many licences I have and their annual cost. I have a calculation at the bottom that I would like to auto calculate Total sum by Department (Department categories are Procurement, Design, Architecture, Admin and Communication)

To do this, Row 3 has all of the department names in it. Row 6 has Annual cost for the licence, how do I then create a formula that only adds up "annual Cost total" cells when it contains the word"procurement" in the same column.

This is quite hard to explain but please see the attached image.

[image]

I would be extremely grateful for you assistance, I have tried Excel bot but the formulas are not working for me.

Comment: That is a needlessly complicated way of doing things.  https://www.wps.com/academy/how-to-sum-if-cell-contains-text-in-excel-quick-tutorials-1864717/ & 
https://exceljet.net/formulas/sum-if-cell-contains-text-in-another-cell